# A 3x3 grid of numbers with unique row and column ranges

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

Can you place every number from 1 to 9 into a 3x3 grid such that the range of every row and column is a unique value? The range of a row is the difference between its maximum and minimum values (similarly for columns).

Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one solution:

> ```
>  1 3 9   8
>  5 7 6   2
>  4 8 2   6
>  
>  4 5 7
> ```

I solved it by

> first placing the 1 and 9 in one row, to get the largest range. The next numbers I placed were 2, 8, 3, 7, 4, 6, 5. In other words I worked from the outside (largest/smallest) inwards. Each time I tried to place the number such that a new row/column would provide the next missing range or do nothing.

Comment: If you swap col1 and col2, the leading diagonal has range 3.

Comment: @JMP That is nice. Of course it is impossible for both diagonals to take part since the only possible ranges are 2 to 8, i.e. just 7 possible values.

Answer (score 2):

It is

> Possible

Because

> 1 3 9
>  4 5 8
>  7 6 2
>
>  Will do.. and I just trying to place them one by one and find this with no difficulty..